# Prime ideals of a lattice

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, lattice-orders

Given the lattice generated by natural numbers (all except $0$) ordered by divisibility, how can I construct its prime ideals? How does a familiy of prime ideals without any given element $a$ look like?

Comment: a lattice generated by natural numbers, or **the** lattice of natural numbers ordered by divisibility? Also, do you consider $0$ to be a natural number (maybe not relevant)?

Comment: @ amrsa I've meant the lattice of all natural numbers except $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf D = (D,|) = (D,\gcd,\mathrm{lcm})$ and $\mathcal I_p(\mathbf D)$ denote the set of prime ideals of $\mathbf D$.

Let $I_{p^k}$ denote the set of natural numbers which are **not** multiples of the prime power $p^k$.
It is easy to check that $I_{p^k} \in \mathcal I_p(\mathbf D)$.

Now let $I$ be any other kind of ideal of $\mathbf D$, that is, there exist prime powers $p^{k}$ and $q^{k'}$ (with $p \neq q$) such that $p^k,q^{k'} \notin I$.
Let $n$ be any member of $I$, and define $u=p^kn$ and $v=q^{k'}n$.
Clearly, $u,v \notin I$ (for otherwise $p^k,q^{k'} \in I$), but $\gcd(u,v)=n \in I$, and so $I$ is not a prime ideal.

Hence, an ideal $I$ of $\mathbf D$ is prime iff $I=I_{p^k}$, for some prime number $p$ and natural $k$.

It follows from that description that
$$X_a = \{I \in \mathcal I_p(\mathbf D) : a \notin I\} = \{I_{p^k} : p^k \not\mid a\}.$$

---

Update: I changed $I_p$, for some prime number $p$ to $I_{p^k}$, to some prime number $p$ and natural $k$.
Indeed, the set of numbers not multiples of any power of a prime is a prime ideal.

Comment: @ amrsa I think I didn't understand how you got $p$ and $q$. What if $I=D$?

Comment: @ElmarGuseinov Well, according to the definition I'm used to, a prime ideal is always proper, so that would already be excluded. That said, when I wrote "any other kind of ideal", I meant $I$ a proper ideal that misses more than one prime number, and so there are at least two that don't belong to it.

Comment: @ amrsa I've understood, but why does your proof work in both cases-before editing and after?

Comment: @ElmarGuseinov It didn't work before editing. I had overlooked this case. And actually I also have to adapt the proof that any other kind of proper ideal is not prime. I'll do it now. Done! So I was actually missing a whole lot of prime ideals. I hope it is correct now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If $I$ is not $Ip^k$ for any $p$ and $k$, it means that $I$ contains at least one multiple of $p^k$ for any $p$ and $k$. So, the assertion about $p$ and $q$ is not right?

Comment: @ElmarGuseinov I don't understand what are you referring to. Is it the proof before I changed to $p^k$ and $q^{k'}$? If that is so, then yes, that proof was wrong (it'd be fine for the previous erroneous characterization of prime ideals).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100334/discussion-between-elmar-guseinov-and-amrsa).